# Angular UI-Grid single filter not working - It's only working for 2 characters, not for whole string

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have implemented angular UI-Grid, and it's single filter but the filter is only working for 2 characters, it's not showing any columns if whole string/column value is put in the input box. Below is my code,

```
                 <input class="form-control" ng-change="refreshData(searchText)" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText" />

<div id="grid1" ng-if="gridOptions.data.length>0" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid grid-fontSize"></div>
```

**JS code,**

```
$scope.refreshData = function (termObj) {
       $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

       while (termObj) {
           var oSearchArray = termObj.split(' ');
           $scope.filterGrid1.data = $filter('filter')($scope.gridOptions.data, oSearchArray[0], undefined);
           oSearchArray.shift();
           termObj = (oSearchArray.length !== 0) ? oSearchArray.join(' ') : '';
       }
   };
```

I  am getting data from http call and saving into data variable and using it for search and populating data to the grid.
Note: I have also tried ,

```
$scope.refreshData = function() {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = $filter('filter')(data, $scope.searchText, undefined);
   };
```

But neither of them is working, it only works for the 2 characters , but when I put the whole string, even though there is matching column grid doesn't shows anything.

Any solution or ideas will be helpful, Thanks in advance.
**Here is a plunker** [plunker, implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMXmzQ5blLLuXbceU623?p=preview)  having the same issue, also I want a search on the select, dropdown also for the second field,
**Issue: - Gladys Rivas, record is there, if I am searching with "Gladys Rivas" no result, but if with "Gla" I can see the record.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the doc carefully?

Apparently

```
$filter('filter')(data, $scope.searchText, undefined);
```

cannot filter all the data automatically.

There is a full example in below doc:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/321_singleFilter

Since to many places you need to change, i suggest you see the doc carefully before any further step.